# Get rid of sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop executeAcceptLoop error

Tags: java, tcp, error-handling, rmi

I have searched a lot but I could not find any good solution to suppress this error message,

```
2011.10.14 15:16:38:751 ERROR 14 Oct, 2011 3:16:38 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop executeAcceptLoop
2011.10.14 15:16:38:751 ERROR WARNING: RMI TCP Accept-0: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=8006] throws
2011.10.14 15:16:38:751 ERROR java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
2011.10.14 15:16:38:752 ERROR at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
2011.10.14 15:16:38:752 ERROR at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
2011.10.14 15:16:38:752 ERROR at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
2011.10.14 15:16:38:753 ERROR at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
2011.10.14 15:16:38:753 ERROR at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(Unknown Source)
2011.10.14 15:16:38:753 ERROR at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(Unknown Source)
2011.10.14 15:16:38:754 ERROR at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I find in internet that we can get rid of this message by setting log level to SEVERE for sun.rmi.transport.tcp as below,

```
Logger tcpLogger = Logger.getLogger("sun.rmi.transport.tcp");  
tcpLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

but wouldn't suppress other useful error messages?

Can any one suggest me a better solution to avoid this error?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition itself is entirely benign, I don't know why they log it as a warning. Normally this logger is turned off completely unless you are debugging your remote objects.

Comment: you mean to say there is no harm to set loglevel to SEVERE for this logger to supress the error?

Comment: @swd No, I meant to say what I *did* say. You can turn it off altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get rid of those log entries by adding to the `JAVA_OPTS`:

```
 -XX:+UseVMInterruptibleIO
```

See: [RMI TCP Accept Loop throws java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument in Native method](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2012-August/004830.html)